# This script was running successful and now it is not. That shows <<Exception: Service error: Spreadsheets>> error. How to make correct this vba?

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

```
function Movedata2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Receipt");
  var formRng = formSheet.getRange("B12:AA44");
  var formData = formRng.getValues();
  var dataSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Historical Sales");
  dataSheet.getRange(dataSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, formData.length, formData[0].length).setValues(formData); 
}
```

Comment: That's not VBA...  Google sheets?

Comment: Thanks for responding. It is google apps script on google sheets XD

Comment: It seems to work just fine for me.  Perhaps you can explain in detail what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

#### It runs this way

```
function Movedata2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var rg = sh.getRange("B12:AA44");
  var vs = rg.getValues();
  var osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs); 
}
```

Comment: That's an error too. Service error: Spreadsheets!

Comment: I tested the code.  I changed the names of the sheets and it works fine.   So you might like to try the code in another container

Comment: Okay, I'll try the code with another container. Thank you.